# How to create clickable table of contents using pdfbox?

Tags: pdfbox

I have multiple pdf files which will be merged to create a final pdf file. A clickable table of contents need to be created for the final pdf. I am able to merge all the pdfs but unable to create clickable table of contents using pdfbox. Can anyone help in this ?

I tried using PDActionGoTo,PDAnnotationLink  etc.But unable to achieve it.

Comment: See the AddAnnotations.java example in the source code download, in the examples subproject. However you'll still have to do the positioning and the texts yourself.